# tensorboard on mac has VersionConflict error

Tags: macos, tensorboard

macbookpro 10.13.3
python 2.7
tensorflow 2.1

tensorflow installed and running ok, I can run a simple demo. but tensorboard error.

> fransontekiMacBook-Pro-2:bin franson$ tensorboard Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File "/usr/local/bin/tensorboard", line 11, in
>   
>       sys.exit(run_main())   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorboard/main.py", line 59,
>   in run_main
>       default.get_plugins() + default.get_dynamic_plugins(),   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorboard/default.py", line
>   115, in get_dynamic_plugins
>       for entry_point in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points('tensorboard_plugins')   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 2331, in load
>       self.require(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 2354, in require
>       items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer, extras=self.extras)   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 786, in resolve
>       raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req) pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (setuptools 40.4.3
>   (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
>   Requirement.parse('setuptools>=41.0.0'))

Answer (score 1):

You have to update your tensorbaord version by running `pip install --upgrade tensorboard`

This answer gives a detailed explaination 
[Upgrade tensorboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49791011/tensorflow-version-vs-tensorboard-version)